# Building a hash from lines input

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Given the lines with a colon as a separator -

```
1:s11-base:running:/zones/s11-base:3f9d522c:solaris:excl:-:none:<br>
2:s11-template:running:/zones/s11-template:ce57a4db:solaris:excl:-:none:<br>
...
```

how can I create a hash like

```
"zoneid" => "1",
"zonename" => "s11-base",
"state" => "running",
```

next hash

```
"zoneid" => "2",
"zonename" => "s11-template",
"state" => "running",
```

and so on.

I want to iterate over all lines, and assign the specific value to the keys from each line.

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Answer (score 2):

Anything like this?

```
input.lines.map do |line|
  id, name, state = line.split(":")
  { "zoneid" => id, "zonename" => name, "state" => state }
end
```

Comment: Pretty clean but the `, _` after `id, name, state` seems unnecessary.

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#split`:

```
str = "1:s11-base:running:/zones/s11-base:3f9d522c:solaris:excl:-:none:<br>"

splitted_str = str.split(":")
# => ["1", "s11-base", "running", "/zones/s11-base", "3f9d522c", "solaris", "excl", "-", "none", "<br>"]

my_hash = {"zoneid": splitted_str[0], "zonename": splitted_str[1], "state" => splitted_str[2]}
# => {:zoneid=>"1", :zonename=>"s11-base", "state"=>"running"}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. How you did it, was also my first idea, but I couldn't make it unfortunately